# Web part category, only see"list and library"

Tags: web-part

I'm a full control user. When I click add web part. I can only see "List and library" in categories. As i am fully new to Sharepoint, can you please give me a detailed guideline on how to solve this problem.

Maybe there is something need to be change in site collection root. but i can't find which is the root site.

Comment: which version of SharePoint yo are using 2010,2013 or online?

Comment: SharePoint Online

Answer (score 1):

@Hardik: You don't need to be site collection admin to view or add web parts. Sheesh!

Crystal, SharePoint Online still has a version and also comes in many flavours from Education to Enterprise. I would suggest you find this information out first.

Other questions ahd factors to consider:

- What are you "adding a webpart" to - a web part page, publishing page, list form view...?
- What type of site are we dealing with - public or intranet?
- What features are enabled for the site?

You can usually, but not always, determine the root site from the URL. If you're not a portal administrator I'd be asking someone higher up the food chain to help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check whether you are a site collection administrator:

Navigate through ribbon to Site Settings ->Users and Permissions->Site collection Administrators

if you can see the above option then you should get the permissions.